# MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, '') when closing a SQL query with mysqlclient 2.0.3. Is it because of the connection?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

When executing some SQL queries on the user table in my ETL I get an error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools>python -m etl.main
2021-06-29 15:34:53.515286 - Connecting to database hozana_data...
2021-06-29 15:34:53.523283 - Connecting to archive database hozana_archive...
2021-06-29 15:34:53.755949 - Start ETL main process
2021-06-29 15:34:53.755949 - `users` table:
2021-06-29 15:34:53.755949 - Hashing column `users`.`email:`table_name:  users
c.execute("SELECT 15+10 FROM users"):  0
 done.
2021-06-29 15:34:53.763899 - Hashing column `users`.`email_notification:`table_name:  users
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\task\anonymization.py", line 18, in hash_column
    print("c.execute(\"""SELECT 15+10 FROM users\"""): ", c.execute("""SELECT 15+10 FROM users"""))
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 183, in execute
    while self.nextset():
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 137, in nextset
    nr = db.next_result()
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, '')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\main.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\main.py", line 24, in main
    anonymization.main()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\task\anonymization.py", line 61, in main
    hash_column('users', 'email_notification', 'user_id', True)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\task\anonymization.py", line 52, in hash_column
    print('.', end='', flush=True)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 239, in __exit__
    self.close()
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, '')
```

I don't get it. This error seems to be because of a closed connection or too much data ... But I only have the schema, the database is empty. And even when I do a simple math operation I get this error:

Here is part of the ETL:

```
from etl.mysql.operations import drop_column_if_exists
from etl.utils.logging import info
from etl.mysql.connect import db, db_name
from etl.utils.array import chunks


def hash_column(table_name, column_name, pk_name, email_mode=False):
    # Executed a query that will overwrite a column with an hashed version of its content.
    # With email mode, the domain name will be kept:
    # aba@stoacj.com -> 379ac32fe8f576c4c63b17cd576e6c40c7dcd[...]b04c7a4695a7baa54ad5ce44528a0b30ab@stoacj.com
    info('Hashing column `{table_name}`.`{column_name}:`'
         .format(table_name=table_name, column_name=column_name), end='', flush=True)

    with db as c:
        # Execute the update in batches, to avoid "Lock wait timeout exceeded"
        c = c.cursor()
        print("table_name: ", table_name)
        print("c.execute(\"""SELECT 15+10 FROM users\"""): ", c.execute("""SELECT 15+10 FROM users"""))
        c.execute("""
            SELECT {pk_name} as row_id
            FROM {table_name} 
            WHERE {column_name} IS NOT NULL AND {column_name} NOT LIKE 'hash_%'
            ORDER BY row_id ASC
        """.format(table_name=table_name, column_name=column_name, pk_name=pk_name))
        ids = []
...
```

Here is the code in `from etl.mysql.connect import db`:

```
import os
import MySQLdb

from etl.utils.logging import info

db_host = os.environ['DATA_DB_HOST']
db_port = int(os.environ['DATA_DB_PORT'])
db_user = os.environ['DATA_DB_USER']
db_password = os.environ['DATA_DB_PASSWORD']
db_name = os.environ['DATA_DB_NAME']
db_name_archive = os.environ['DATA_DB_ARCHIVE_NAME']

info("Connecting to database {}...".format(db_name))
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=db_host,
                     port=db_port,
                     db=db_name,
                     user=db_user,
                     passwd=db_password)
```

The problem isn't because of the connection, I have it and it's okay.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I tried to increment `max_allowed_packet`:

```
mysql> select @@max_allowed_packet;
+----------------------+
| @@max_allowed_packet |
+----------------------+
|              4194304 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=10485760;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

But it is still the same space:

```
mysql> select @@max_allowed_packet;
+----------------------+
| @@max_allowed_packet |
+----------------------+
|              4194304 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+---------+
| Variable_name      | Value   |
+--------------------+---------+
| max_allowed_packet | 4194304 |
+--------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

## Logs

Here are today's log

```
2021-07-06T09:23:01.193756Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-07-06T09:23:01.195707Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2021-07-06T09:23:01.198594Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.34-log) starting as process 18804 ...
2021-07-06T09:23:01.223999Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-07-06T09:23:01.224707Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-07-06T09:23:01.225130Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2021-07-06T09:23:01.225747Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-07-06T09:23:01.226251Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
2021-07-06T09:23:01.230045Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-07-06T09:23:01.232177Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2021-07-06T09:23:01.237646Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 8M, instances = 1, chunk size = 8M
2021-07-06T09:23:01.239234Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-07-06T09:23:01.284231Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2021-07-06T09:23:01.476328Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-07-06T09:23:01.477358Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-07-06T09:23:01.512811Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-07-06T09:23:01.515027Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2021-07-06T09:23:01.516117Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2021-07-06T09:23:01.517118Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-07-06T09:23:01.578331Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.34 started; log sequence number 3981806
2021-07-06T09:23:01.579551Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-07-06T09:23:01.581274Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2021-07-06T09:23:01.599250Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210706 11:23:01
2021-07-06T09:23:01.616013Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2021-07-06T09:23:01.616947Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2021-07-06T09:23:01.621001Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-07-06T09:23:01.621875Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2021-07-06T09:23:01.623118Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2021-07-06T09:23:01.623813Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2021-07-06T09:23:01.624196Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2021-07-06T09:23:01.624656Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-07-06T09:23:01.675585Z 0 [Note] Failed to start slave threads for channel ''
2021-07-06T09:23:01.737678Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2021-07-06T09:23:01.738400Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.34-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2021-07-06T09:24:16.925420Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'hozana'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

## Advise

my experience with mysqlclient is a real disaster:

With Fedora:

- With mysqlclient==1.3.7 (which we are using on Debian):
  `mysql_config` missing, even when reinstalling connectors such as `mariadb-connector-c-devel` or `community-mysql-devel`
- With 2.0.3:
  MySQL-python is missing, or not recognized

With Windows:

- With `mysqlclient==1.3.7` ,
  I can't install it: tells me to use Visual C++ but nothing changes. So I've tried a pre-built version from Christoph Gohlke's site but it's not compatible.
- With >2.* I have **[this question]**:
  `OperationalError: (2006, '')` in a large part of SQL queries like the following one:

```py
c.execute("""
        UPDATE `{table_name}` 
        SET `{column_name}` = CONCAT('hash_', {expression})
        WHERE {pk_name} IN ({ids})
    """.format(
        table_name=table_name, column_name=column_name, expression=expression, pk_name=pk_name,
        ids=','.join(ids)
    ))
```

## Start of a solution

I don't have this issue anymore when upgrading the code to enable it to use mysqlclient 2.0.3 and containerizing MySQL:

```
(venv) [ac@localmachine data-tools]$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
       - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
       - .data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

volumes:
  schema_database_metabase.sql:
```

I know, it looks crazy it works. I think I need to add a few more details.

Comment: How do you connect to mysql? Which package you use? What exactly is under `from etl.mysql.connect import db`?

Comment: Is it the first time you deploy the app to this machine? Has the app itself worked correctly before, maybe on your local development box? What is in the network path between your app and the database?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @cidermole . It is the first time I deploy this app to this machine: my localhost . The app seems to work correctly on his deployed environment. I don't know what's a network path but the host is on 127.0.0.1 :)

Comment: Thanks for your help @AdamTokarski I just added it

Comment: if you set globally then check variable value like `show global variables like 'max_allowed_packet';`

Comment: WOuld love to do so @ROHITKHURANA, but mysql CLI now keeps crashing ... Even after rebooting

Comment: yes, error **MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, '')** seems your mysql is getting restart. Please share mysql error logs

Comment: Sure, @ROHITKHURANA where do I find them?

Comment: OperationalError: (2006, '') means "MySQL server has gone away". This error occurs either MySQL crashing/restarting or we are getting a timeout.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: I just added them @ROHITKHURANA But when I try to connect from my script nothing seem to log

Comment: can you share the value of wait_timeout and interactive_wait_timeout of MySQL along with uptime of MySQL database? and add max_allowed_packet=10485760 in my.cnf under mysqld section.

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica if you found a solution, you can add it as an answer and accept it (after 2 days or so). :-)

Answer (score 0):

Many settings work this way:

1. There is a `GLOBAL` setting (4M in your example)
2. You log in; this copies the `GLOBALs` into the `SESSION` settings; you now have 4M
3. (The mistake)  `SET GLOBAL` only sets the `GLOBAL` for *future* logins.
4. (3 different fixes) `SET SESSION max_allowed_packet=10485760;`  Or re-login.  Or change my.cnf, then re-login.
5. But... The `SESSION` setting will go away when you log out.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Yet I get: `ERROR 1621 (HY000): SESSION variable 'max_allowed_packet' is read-only. Use SET GLOBAL to assign the value` when using `SET SESSION` ... Furthermore I didn' thought it would be that heavy. Indeed, I am working on a schema, my database is empty